# Firebase Realtime REST onDisconnect

Tags: c#, firebase, http, firebase-realtime-database

We are building a presence system for our Xamarin.Forms app that utilizes Firebase as it's backend.

Early in development we took the decision to use a wrapper library for the Realtime Database REST API (https://github.com/step-up-labs/firebase-database-dotnet) instead of using the native libraries for IOS & Android.

So far it has saved a great deal of time but now we are running into problems implementing a onDisconnect like system.

I have been digging in the Android and JS firebase libraries on github and found that the client libraries send a specific action parameter shown below. They seem to pass the constant "o" to indicate a onDisconnect push.

```java
private static final String REQUEST_ACTION_ONDISCONNECT_PUT = "o";

...

  @Override
  public void onDisconnectPut(List<String> path, Object data, RequestResultCallback onComplete) {
    this.hasOnDisconnects = true;
    if (canSendWrites()) {
      sendOnDisconnect(REQUEST_ACTION_ONDISCONNECT_PUT, path, data, onComplete);
    } else {
      onDisconnectRequestQueue.add(
          new OutstandingDisconnect(REQUEST_ACTION_ONDISCONNECT_PUT, path, data, onComplete));
    }
    doIdleCheck();
  }
```

Is there any way you can send this action parameter with the Firebase Realtime Database REST api?

Thank you for your time.
Cheers

Comment: Can you dispose instead of disconnect?  Putting the connect object in a "Using" will automatically do a dispose when you exit the using.

Comment: @jdweng thank you for your answer but i think you misunderstood my problem. I'm referring to https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DatabaseReference.html#onDisconnect() a function that allows one to schedule a database operation to run whenever the client loses connection. Example: changing the users online status to "Offline"

Comment: The link you provided looks like methods that are run on a Database Service.  Not the client.  Your first sentence says "Xamarin.Forms app" which is a client not a service.

Answer (score 0):

The native Firebase Realtime Database SDKs for iOS, Android and Web use a persistent Web Socket to keep an open connection between each client and the server. The server uses this Web Socket to detect when the client disconnects, and when that happens it will execute any `onDisconnect` handlers that the client may have attached.

The Firebase Realtime Database's REST API is connectionless, as it uses regular HTTP(S) calls for the traffic between the client and server. There is no way to attach `onDisconnect` handlers through the REST API.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Frank. Hmm i guess I'll have to rethink our firebase integration or add a 3rd party service into the mix. Is there any documentation on creating your own websocket connection to the realtime database?

Comment: The wire protocol is not documented. If you want to use `onDisconnect` handlers, consider using the native SDKs (through Xamarin/C# wrappers).